# Why do my Spring Sessions keep getting deleted from my JDBC store?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, session, spring-session

I am using Spring Sessions with Postgres. The sessions are persisted into my Postgres database using the `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository`.

The default inactive time that I am using for my sessions is 30 days. Once a user logs in, I do `request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval()` and change it to 180 days.

However for some reason the 180 days is not being respected and sessions keep getting deleted every hour. For example:

[image]

This session should have lasted 180 days but it got deleted as soon as the next hour started.

Does anyone know how I can stop these sessions from getting deleted and have them stick around for 180 days?

I am guessing [this function](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/jdbc/JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java#L464) has something to do with this.

Here's the part of my application that extends the user's max inactive interval:

```
private void setupSession(HttpServletRequest request, User user) {
   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   session.setMaxInactiveInterval(15552000);
   session.setAttribute("user-id", user.id);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your configuration?

Comment: If I understood well... you want that unlogged users have a session expiration time of 30 days and logged users 180 days?

Comment: Turns out this is a bug in the library: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/580

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, this is a problem with Spring Session JDBC integration which has been reported in [gh-580](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/580).

To work around this until the solution is delivered, you can extend the `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` and override `cleanUpExpiredSessions` method. After that you just need to override the default JDBC session repository bean by providing your bean that extends `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` and is named `sessionRepository` (bean name is important since it has to match the one in `JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration` in order to override it).

For example:

```
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
class SessionConfig {

    // omitted data source & tx manager config

    @Bean
    MyJdbcOperationsSessionRepository sessionRepository(...) {
        return new ...
    }

}
```

You can find the solution for `cleanUpExpiredSessions` outlined in comments on [gh-580](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/580).

Comment: Thanks for the nudge @AzhaguSurya, I've updated the bad links.